# why I am getting two result for the same url in reactjs routing?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom

I have created demo project to check if the dynamic routing will work or not!!!

in that Project I'm facing issues for two routes which are as follows:

1. gj:jquery
2. ghj:jquery

Here I am passing a parameter called jquery and this route will render on Dynamic component.

on Dynamic Component I'm returning some text based on the page and page type.
my code is like below.

```
componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
        let pagetype = Object.values(this.props.match.params)[0];

    let page2=this.props.location.pathname.split(":")[1];
    let pageName=this.props.location.pathname.split(":")[0].replace("/","");

    //alert("Hello, My type is " + pagetype);
    this.setState({
        type:page2,
        page:pageName
    })
}

 _getCurrentPage=()=>{
        switch(this.state.type){
            case "image":
                return (<h1>pageName: {this.state.page}  pagetype:{this.state.type}</h1>);
            case "formio":
                return (<h1>pageName: {this.state.page}  pagetype:{this.state.type}</h1>);
            case "jquery":
                return (<h1>pageName: {this.state.page}  pagetype:{this.state.type}</h1>);
            case "website":
                return (<h1>pageName: {this.state.page}  pagetype:{this.state.type}</h1>);
            default:
                return (<h1>No match</h1>);

        }
    }

 render(){

    return(
       this._getCurrentPage()
    )
```

Now here for above two routes, I am getting output for two time something like below pairs.

if i first click on any other route and then click on gj > ghj and ghj > gj I am getting following output

```
pageName: gj pagetype:jquery
pageName: ghj pagetype:jquery

pageName: gj pagetype:jquery
pageName: gj pagetype:jquery
```

if i first click on any other route and then click on ghj > gj and gj > ghj I am getting following output

```
pageName: ghj pagetype:jquery
pageName: gj pagetype:jquery

pageName: ghj pagetype:jquery
pageName: ghj pagetype:jquery
```

**what can be the reason for rendering text two times?** 
I logged pageType,pageName and it seems ok. for other routes it is working fine.